# LVM in small ubuntu box?

Tags: lvm

I have a intel NUC for TV and movies and i have installed lvm2. I think it is used, but I feel I have no use for it. The box has got only a 128GB ssd.
How can I deinstall lvm2?

vgdisplay says:

```
     --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <118,74 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              30397
  Alloc PE / Size       30397 / <118,74 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               1oJZS0-NwdL-ll5V-W23D-xILK-r4eI-ZY1mbx
```

And pvdisplay:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               118,74 GiB / not usable 3,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              30397
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          30397
  PV UUID               WQ1hLV-TjXd-Lo1a-4GpQ-qRyC-SAdi-J1G9UN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove LVM so easy. You need to:

1. Make full backup of all files on in your filesystem(s)
2. Run live CD
3. Remove the partition `/dev/sda2`
4. Recreate partition(s) (depend of the filesystems, logical volumes
   you have)
5. Restore from backup.
6. Edit `/etc/fstab` to reflect the new filesystems and mountpoints
7. Edit grub config to reflect the swap place and new partitions and
   reinstall/reinitialize to reflect changes
8. Reinitialize swap (disable it from `/etc/fstab` on 1st boot, reboot, exec
   `mkswap /dev/sdN`, then `swapon /dev/sdN` to activate it, then edit
   `/etc/fstab` to activate it on next boot)

In general LVM make quite small overhead on disk operations so better keep it.

Comment: Additional steps would be needed, adapt `/ec/fstab`, reinstall Grub. If a swap-file is used more steps needed depending on the backup method. So I really agree with your conclusion.

Comment: @mook765, thank you for reminder, will edit my answer to add the steps you mention :)